# how angularjs finds correct property from return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

angular uses watchers to detect property changes and call a listener function , a watcher declaration is for example;

```
$scope.food = "chicken";
scope.$watch(
    function() { return food; },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
        // Only increment the counter if the value changed
           scope.foodCounter = scope.foodCounter + 1; }}
);
```

first param is only just a function with return value , but how does angular know this is the food property from return value . how is this possible

Comment: There is no property you want to watch in function?

Comment: You misunderstand the concept. The watcher you wrote has nothing to do with $scope.food change detection, it's just one more watcher that will fire when $scope.food changes in the first place, but Angular won't use custom watcher to update $scope.food.

Comment: there are two methods (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope ) , by name and by function , both are working i tested , but  i wonder how second one (by function) is working from return value .how the deduction correct variable from return value is possible with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Angular will execute your function, store the result.
To see if something changed, he will simply execute the function again, and see if the value is equal to previous value.

Comment: How it does know this value belongs to food variable ?  if there is another variable called $scope.car ="toyota" , and i register it to watcher , angularjs knows who changed , i think detection which variables from return value is imposible , Because return value from a function string , int values etc... but not variable address or itself , angularjs use a technic here , and my question is how deduction which variable from return value ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think 
you need to pass what you want to keep in watch and whenever the object/variable changes you will have the  old and newvalue

```
$scope.food = "chicken";
$scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.food  },
       function(newValue, oldValue) {
                 //your Code here.It will return the whenever  food value change
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this syntax:

```
scope.$watch('food', function(newValue, oldValue) {
});
```

It's the same as doing:

```
scope.$watch(function() { return food; }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
});
```

Basically what happens, is that the function returns the value being watched and it is called for each turn of the $digest loop, that's why your counter is getting incremented.

Comment: scope.$watch is sensible with name like 'food','car' etc , you already give which variable , but deduction from second method ( from function return value ) is imposible i think.is there a reflection or what ?